# Allow Ad Hoc Distribution Queries for all users

Tags: sql-server

I am using AD Hoc Distribution Queries to transfer Data from MS SQLServer 2008 to MS Access.
The process is started using a single SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO OpenDataSource('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Data Source=C:\temp\target.mdb;User ID=Admin;Password=;')...testtable select * from dbo.testtable
```

To do that I have set the Ad Hoc Distribution Query parameter to 1 via

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
```

Everything works fine as long as the statement is executed with a sysadmin database-permission.

When I try to execute the statement as a normal db-user, the statement fails with a permission denied error message.

How can I grant all users to execute ad hoc distribution statements?

Thanks in advance

Marcus

Comment: Have you played around with the registry settings discussed here? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29256297/nonsa-users-get-access-denied-in-ole-db-query.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(
Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [EggHeadCafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/28910398/opendatasource-authority-on-sql-server-2005.aspx); it seems the common consensus that this is a registry key called `DisallowAdHocAccess`; it needs to exist with the value `0` before users without an `sa` role can execute ad hoc distributed queries.

In the `Server\MSSQL.1\Providers\Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` key, add a `DWORD`
value named `DisallowAdHocAccess` with the value `0`.

Allow ad-hoc access to the Jet provider, by using the registry
(using Management Studio will not work, because it deletes the registry
key instead of setting it to zero, and a missing registry key is
interpreted as "do not allow ad-hoc access").

If you previously got the error, before trying again make sure that
you restart the server or run a `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` command because it seems
that SQL Server won't check the key again if you run the same query
twice.

If anyone has a way that doesn't involve editing the registry though, would be good to hear it.

If this still doesn't work, have you tried setting up a linked server instead? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), [Access Specific Linked Server Tutorial](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Configuring-a-Linked-Microsoft-Access-Server-on-SQL-2005-Server/)

Comment: I used the same solution, but with "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" as the provider key.