# Ad hoc Query permissions SQL Server

Tags: sql, permissions, sql-server-express, adhoc

I have a previous app from XP that I am having to resurrect on WIN 7, SQL Server 2008 Express, and VSC#.

I had a user that could execute the following

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.[CARD DEF GENERAL POINT]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'C:\Users\E151624\Documents\TagConversionRefFiles\Card Def.accdb';'admin';'',[CARD DEF GENERAL POINT])
```

The user connected from the VSC# app and could run the query above.  In recreating the user, it does not have permission to run this query from either the program or a SQL query window.  Currently the user is a SQL Auth user with dbo permissions but this user apparently does not have permissions to access the file on the C: drive.  I tried creating a windows user but even with admin privileges on that user it still does not work so I must be doing something wrong (and I don't recall what the user config was from XP).

By the way ad hoc queries are enabled:

```
name    minimum maximum config_value    run_value
access check cache bucket count 0   16384   0   0
access check cache quota    0   2147483647  0   0
Ad Hoc Distributed Queries  0   1   1   1
affinity I/O mask   -2147483648 2147483647  0   0
affinity mask   -2147483648 2147483647  0   0
Agent XPs   0   1   0   0
allow updates   0   1   0   0
awe enabled 0   1   0   0
blocked process threshold (s)   0   86400   0   0
c2 audit mode   0   1   0   0
clr enabled 0   1   0   0
cost threshold for parallelism  0   32767   5   5
cross db ownership chaining 0   1   0   0
cursor threshold    -1  2147483647  -1  -1
Database Mail XPs   0   1   0   0
default full-text language  0   2147483647  1033    1033
default language    0   9999    0   0
default trace enabled   0   1   1   1
disallow results from triggers  0   1   0   0
filestream access level 0   2   0   0
fill factor (%) 0   100 0   0
ft crawl bandwidth (max)    0   32767   100 100
ft crawl bandwidth (min)    0   32767   0   0
ft notify bandwidth (max)   0   32767   100 100
ft notify bandwidth (min)   0   32767   0   0
index create memory (KB)    704 2147483647  0   0
in-doubt xact resolution    0   2   0   0
lightweight pooling 0   1   0   0
locks   5000    2147483647  0   0
max degree of parallelism   0   64  0   0
max full-text crawl range   0   256 4   4
max server memory (MB)  16  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647
max text repl size (B)  -1  2147483647  65536   65536
max worker threads  128 32767   0   0
media retention 0   365 0   0
min memory per query (KB)   512 2147483647  1024    1024
min server memory (MB)  0   2147483647  0   8
nested triggers 0   1   1   1
network packet size (B) 512 32767   4096    4096
Ole Automation Procedures   0   1   0   0
open objects    0   2147483647  0   0
optimize for ad hoc workloads   0   1   0   0
PH timeout (s)  1   3600    60  60
precompute rank 0   1   0   0
priority boost  0   1   0   0
query governor cost limit   0   2147483647  0   0
query wait (s)  -1  2147483647  -1  -1
recovery interval (min) 0   32767   0   0
remote access   0   1   1   1
remote admin connections    0   1   0   0
remote login timeout (s)    0   2147483647  20  20
remote proc trans   0   1   0   0
remote query timeout (s)    0   2147483647  600 600
Replication XPs 0   1   0   0
scan for startup procs  0   1   0   0
server trigger recursion    0   1   1   1
set working set size    0   1   0   0
show advanced options   0   1   1   1
SMO and DMO XPs 0   1   1   1
SQL Mail XPs    0   1   0   0
transform noise words   0   1   0   0
two digit year cutoff   1753    9999    2049    2049
user connections    0   32767   0   0
user instance timeout   5   65535   60  60
user instances enabled  0   1   1   1
user options    0   32767   0   0
xp_cmdshell 0   1   1   1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I had to create a Windows user; add it to the SQL Logins; add it to the membership group for the DB.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has rather complicated permissioning.

I might have this wrong, but I think the permissions for accessing local or network drives is based on the owner of the SQL Server process itself.   If you go to the Control Panel --> Admistrative Tools --> Services, look for MSSQL as a service.  This is the listener process for the database.

One of the columns is "log on as".  That is the user that needs permissions on the file system.

Comment: While you are correct, the OP is not using networked drives.

Comment: @SlogmeisterExtraordinaire . . . The same idea applies to any drive (obviously).  I shouldn't have singled out network drives in the answer, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389312/allow-ad-hoc-distribution-queries-for-all-users).

Note, however, that if you're not using the Jet provider, but using the ACE provider (like I am), you'll have to put the value under that provider's key.